# How can i create a table in sql server 2005 that is totally new for me..?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection

I have one problem in which i simply want to know how i can create a table that can easily Used as a back end for my solution that is in Vb 2010.

I also want to know that when we **choose a data source in a vb.net** that is for sql server Which we want to choose....simply which can be used Because there is 2 or 3 with little different name.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand your question, but in an effort to help:
I'm guessing that you want to programmatically create a table to be used by other parts of your VB application, but that you need to ensure the table name is unique...? If I'm right in that assumption, then see below.

You can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

To get a list of table names currently in your database. You can compare the TABLE_NAME column values with your desired table name. If it exists already, change the name by adding an differentiator, eg: MyTable, MyTable1, MyTable2 etc.

Alternatively, SQL Server accepts Guids as table names.

**Disclaimer:** IMHO, If your table is not going to be temporary deciding table names in this manner is a pretty ugly solution and lacks supportability.

Comment: ok.....but sorry i am not writ a well quetion...But i want a step to create a table IN sql server.....please help me out...

Comment: Ok, sure. So you'll need create a CREATE TABLE script (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx) A little tip to help you out, if you're really struggling: Design your table in SQL Server Management Studio. When you're happy with it, right click the table and choose Script Table as -> CREATE To -> New Query Editor Window. This will open a query editor window with the SQL command needed to create that table. This will be the command you need to execute in your application.